# List of different unknown mining pools

Tags: blockchain, mining-pools, mining-theory, block, privacy

A miner can identify himself when he receive  his coinbase transaction, we can view them on website offering block explorer like https://www.blockchain.com/charts/pools

Some of these miners are listed as Unknown because blockchain.com has been unable to identify them

> A large portion of Unknown blocks does not mean an attack on the network, it simply means we have been unable to determine the origin.

But when we click on one of those block mined by an Unknown miner we can see that most of them reuse the same addresses for their coinbase transaction but blockchain.com does not seem to list those reused Unknown address, **is there a place to see a listing of those unknown reused addresses** so that we can know how concentrated those miners are, or at least what they want us to know because I guess each time it could have been the same miner using a different addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: mining-pool-dist]

Source: https://btc.bitaps.com/blocks

blockchain.com [mentioned](https://www.blockchain.com/btc/block/000000000000000000005580c3003ae8990deecc53448713b09c270731f7b470) `unknown` for block `649390`

Whereas btc.bitaps.com shows "Huobi" as mining pool for the same block: https://btc.bitaps.com/649390

Coinbase text: `=h_HZ/HuoBi/mmwta@F,Cn3ǐIK(`